# display:none not working in popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display [this](http://jsfiddle.net/RY9tk/208/) popup on [JSGCL](http://jsgcl.com/#) website. It does display the popup but it neither displays the text of the popup nor close the popup on pressing close.

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div >
        <h1>JamaPunji</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.jamapunji.pk/" target="_blank">Click here</a> to get details.</p>
       <a href="#" id="close_popup">Close</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup{
    position: absolute;
    background: #004990;
    top: 45%;
    left: 45%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index:9999;
} 
#close_popup {
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
#popup h1,#popup p, #popup a{
    text-align:center;
    z-index:9999;
}
#popup a{
    color:#F47B20;
      z-index:9999;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {    $("#popup").css("display", "block");
  });

  $("#close_popup").click(function(){
    $("#popup").css("display", "none");
  });
```

Comment: It;s working on the fiddle. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DOM is broken.

The original code is missing a `</div>` closing tag.

```
<div id="popup">
    <div >
        <h1>JamaPunji</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.jamapunji.pk/" target="_blank">Click here</a> to get details.</p>
       <a href="#" id="close_popup">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it also seems on the JSGCL the $ is not mapped to jQuery, so you should also change your js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#popup").css("display", "block");
    jQuery("#close_popup").click(function(){
        jQuery("#popup").css("display", "none");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Changed both the points mentioned but still the problem is there.

Comment: in the JSGCL website? i didn't see any changes in view source

Answer (score 1):

In your websitescript `jQuery.noConflict()` is called on the jQuery file to use a slider or something. This means `$` doesn't work, but `jQuery` does, so your code should look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#popup").css("display", "block");
    jQuery("#close_popup").click(function(){
        jQuery("#popup").css("display", "none");
    }); 
});
```