# Close button not working in popup

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a popup. It works fine on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RY9tk/210/) but when I port it to the [website](http://jsgcl.com/#), the close button does not work. Please guide me how can I make it work. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
        <h1>JamaPunji</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.jamapunji.pk/" target="_blank">Click here</a> to get details.</p>
       <a href="#" id="close_popup">Close</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup{
    position: absolute;
    background: #004990;
    top: 45%;
    left: 45%;
    width: 300px;
   /* height: 200px;*/
    /* border: 1px solid #000; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index:9999;
} 
#close_popup {
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
#popup h1,#popup p, #popup a{
    text-align:center;
    z-index:9999;
}
#popup a{
    color:#F47B20;
      z-index:9999;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#popup").css("display", "block");
    jQuery("#close_popup").click(function(){
        jQuery("#popup").css("display", "none");
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your website has a Javascript error, fix it and try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [display:none not working in popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959291/displaynone-not-working-in-popup)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 same id #popup in your page.. This may cause a problem before hiding..

Comment: I unknowingly did this by adding SelectFeature controls to the map. 

After clicking your popup, see if $("[id=pop_close]") returns more than 1 element. 

I used this to check if the close button was triggering:

$("#pop_close").trigger("click");

Answer (score 2):

Your website has two elements with the same id. This is not a good practice. IDs are supposed to be unique in an HTML page. So the best thing you can do is to use different IDs or use same class for selection. Using class will lead to closing all the popups if conditions are not provide for closing only the parent popup. There is another way, which is **not advised**.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#popup").css("display", "block");
    jQuery("#close_popup").click(function(){
        jQuery("[id='popup']").hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

or using parent

```
jQuery("#close_popup").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parents('#popup').hide(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your websitescript `jQuery.noConflict()` is called on the jQuery file to use a slider. This means `$` doesn't work, but `jQuery` does. Also change your IDs to classes. You can't have duplicate IDs on your page, it will cause errors. Your code would look like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".popup").css("display", "block");
  jQuery(".close_popup").click(function(){
    jQuery(".popup").css("display", "none");
  }); 
});
```

```css
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  background: #004990;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  width: 300px;
  /* height: 200px;*/
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.close_popup {
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.popup h1,
.popup p,
.popup a {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.popup a {
  color: #F47B20;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popup">
  <h1>JamaPunji</h1>
  <p><a href="http://www.jamapunji.pk/" target="_blank">Click here</a> to get details.</p>
  <a href="#" class="close_popup">Close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the mistake what you are doing repeated id's.Id should be unique everytime.

[image]